# How to create array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create the width array of each children of selected element. I tried :

```
var width = $(element).children().map(function () { return this.style.width; });
```

But this is not working. When i `alert(width[0])` then instead of showing width it shows `objectHtmlElement`. What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `.width()` the style property only works if you set inline styles.

```
var widths = $(element).children().map(function () { return $(this).width(); });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the basic array, you should call `get` method, map method returns a jQuery-wrapped array.

> As the return value is a jQuery-wrapped array, it's very common to get() the returned object to work with a basic array.

```
var widths = $(element).children().map(function() {
     return this.style.width; 
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = $('li');
var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
```

Result would be:

```
(typeof obj === 'object' && obj.jquery) === true;
jQuery.isArray(arr) === true;
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery width() and get() after map:

```
var widths = $(element).children().map(function() {
     return $(this).width(); 
}).get();
```